# Are there any official ways to regain a permanent Willpower point if it is somehow lost?

Tags: world-of-darkness, vampire-the-masquerade

As for now, the only way that I know of is to buy the level again with experience. This would basically mean that after facing some difficulties during a few sessions my character became more resistant to stress (again). However, this is a very expensive thing.

Tremere (or Assamite Sorcerers) will inavitably lose Willpower during their unlife, it's not a question of "if", it's a question of "when". Didn't they find or develop another way of dealing with that risk?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### Nope, you can't

As far as I know, when a **permanent** Willpower dot is spent/lost, it is just gone for good. The only way of regaining it is by using Experience.
Have a look a the rules [here](http://whitewolf.wikia.com/wiki/Willpower) if you need a better clarification (the link covers both the Old World Of Darkness (oWoD) and Chronicles of Darkness, or nWoD).

Comment: I have surely read that article. That's sad, I was waiting for something like first level power of Bardo (allows to regain a Humanity point that was lost less than a week ago). I will wait for some more answeres for some time in case someone finds such a way, and if it doesn't happen, I will accept this answer.

Comment: Thaumatury is a very dangerous discipline, it is stated in all VTM books. That's why Tremere characters usually have high willpower and that's why many tremeres prefer rituals. Also, you should consider using willpower *every* time you use a Path with low chanse of success.